# Couchbase - find document by regexp using uppercase words

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Using couchbase **5.1.1** and java client **2.6.1**.

On database, I have bucket with name *config* and have one document:

```
[
 {
    "section": "MAIL",
    "id": "aaa.1.0.0.MAIL",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "values": {
        "mail" : "test1@test1.com"
    }
 }
]
```

Now, I want to find doucment using regular expresion on fields:

```
bucket.query(new SearchQuery("configindex", SearchQuery.regexp(regexp).field("sectrion"));
```

If I put word using lowercase e.g.: **mail**, everything is fine and I recive document, but if I put word using uppercase like **MAIL**, what is exactly matches with fields value, I have no answear. Can You explain me, why I can't search using uppercase words?

EDIT:

If I put MA.* for regexp - it's not workig, ma.* - was working. I only want to know, why I can't use uppercase on regural expression when I have field value "section" : **"MAIL"**. Why it's not working? but if I put "mail", it means **lowercase** on regexp, everythink was fine...

Comment: Can you share the regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, in case you're using a regex like: `"[a-z]"` it will only work with lowercase characters.

Assuming that your regex is `"[a-z]"` try changing it by `"[A-Za-z]"` which will work for uppercase and lowercase. Something like:

```
bucket.query(new SearchQuery("configindex", SearchQuery.regexp("[A-Za-z]").field("section"));
```

Comment: is not a case. If I want find document with "section" : " MAIL", co I call rest: localhost/config?section=MAIL and it's not working, but if I call localhost/config?section=mail, everyting was fine. That's a case

Comment: Can you share the regex you're using?

Comment: e.g.: MA.* - not workig, ma.* - was working. But I only want to know, why I can't use uppercase on regural expression when I have field value "section" : "MAIL". Why it's not workig? but if I put "mail", it means lowercase on regexp, everythink was fine...